# Trying to import redux from expo snacks to vsc and getting an error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

I am currently trying to implement redux within my code. I have done so in expo snack and it works however when I implement it within vsc it does not work and says undefined is not a function.

this is my actiontypes:

```
import {
FETCH_IMAGES_FAILURE,
FETCH_IMAGES_REQUEST,
FETCH_IMAGES_SUCCESS,
SET_SELECTED_IMAGE,
CLEAR_SELECTED_IMAGE,
} from '../actions/index';

export function FetchImagesRequest() {
return { type: FETCH_IMAGES_REQUEST };
}

export function FetchImagesSuccess(images) {
return { type: FETCH_IMAGES_SUCCESS, payload: images };
}
export function FetchImagesFailure(error) {
return { type: FETCH_IMAGES_FAILURE, payload: error };
}
export function SetSelectedImage(image) {
return { type: SET_SELECTED_IMAGE, payload: image };
}
export function ClearSelectedImage() {
return { type: CLEAR_SELECTED_IMAGE };
}
```

This is my reducer/marsRoverReducer.js:

```
import {
FETCH_IMAGES_REQUEST,
FETCH_IMAGES_SUCCESS,
FETCH_IMAGES_FAILURE,
SET_SELECTED_IMAGE,
CLEAR_SELECTED_IMAGE,
} from '../actions/index';

const initialState = {
images: [],
selectedImage: null,
isLoading: false,
error: null
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
switch (action.type) {
  case FETCH_IMAGES_REQUEST:
    return { ...state, isLoading: true };
  case FETCH_IMAGES_SUCCESS:
    return { ...state, images: action.payload, isLoading: false };
  case FETCH_IMAGES_FAILURE:
    return { ...state, error: action.payload, isLoading: false };
  case SET_SELECTED_IMAGE:
    return { ...state, selectedImage: action.payload };
  case CLEAR_SELECTED_IMAGE:
    return { ...state, selectedImage: null };
  default:
    return state;
}
};

export default reducer;
```

This is my reducer/index.js:

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import reducer from './marsRoverReducer'

export default combineReducers({reducer})
```

This is my store/index.js:

```
 import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
 import reducer from '../reducer/marsRoverReducer'

 export default combineReducers({reducer})
```

This is my code for my marsRoverPhotos:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, FlatList, Image, SafeAreaView, TouchableOpacity, Modal, 
Button } from 'react-native';
import { styles} from '../Style';
import ImageProgress from 'react-native-image-progress';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { FetchImagesFailure, FetchImagesSuccess, FetchImagesRequest, SetSelectedImage, 
ClearSelectedImage } from '../redux/actionTypes/index';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

import { Card } from 'react-native-paper';

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
   return {
     images: state.reducer.images,
     isLoading: state.reducer.isLoading,
     error: state.reducer.error,
     selectedImage: state.reducer.selectedImage,
   };
 };

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
return {
  fetchImagesRequest: () => dispatch(FetchImagesRequest()),
  fetchImagesSuccess: images => dispatch(FetchImagesSuccess(images)),
  fetchImagesFailure: error => dispatch(FetchImagesFailure(error)),
  setSelectedImage: image => dispatch(SetSelectedImage(image)),
  clearSelectedImage: () => dispatch(ClearSelectedImage()),
};
};


 export function MarsRoverPhotos({
navigation,
images,
isLoading,
error,
fetchImagesRequest,
setSelectedImage,
clearSelectedImage,
selectedImage,
fetchImagesSuccess,
fetchImagesFailure
}) {
  const API_URL =
  'https://api.nasa.gov/mars-photos/api/v1/rovers/curiosity/photos?sol=900&page=1&api_key=jk0tEhdHzBqHh7ocLh09zLELJKaHpgiJ3jDVb9bn';

const [imagesFetched, setImagesFetched] = React.useState(false);

const setImages = (images) => {
    fetchImagesSuccess(images);
  };

  const handleImageSelection = (image) => {
    setSelectedImage(image);
    navigation.navigate('ImageDetails');
  };

  const handleModalClose = () => {
    clearSelectedImage();
  };

React.useEffect(() => {
  if (!imagesFetched) {
    fetchImagesRequest();
    fetch(API_URL)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setImages(data.photos);
        setImagesFetched(true);
        console.log(setImages);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        fetchImagesFailure('Error fetching data:', error);
      });
  }
});




const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handleImageSelection(item)}>
    <View>
      <ImageProgress
        source={{ uri: item.img_src }}
        style={{ width: '75%', height: 200, margin: 10 }}
        resizeMode="cover"
      />
      <Text>{item.id}</Text>
    </View>
  </TouchableOpacity>
);

return (
  <View style={[styles.container, { flex: 1 }]}>
    <Text>Mars Rover Photos</Text>
    <Text>Camera: Curiosity</Text>
  
      <FlatList
        data={images}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
      />
    
    {selectedImage ? (
      <Modal visible={true} onRequestClose={() => handleModalClose()}>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Card style={modalStyle.modalView}>
            <ImageProgress
              source={{ uri: selectedImage.img_src }}
              style={{ width: '100%', height: 200 }}
              resizeMode="cover"
            />
            <Text>{selectedImage.id}</Text>
            <Text>{selectedImage.camera.name}</Text>
            <Button title="Close" onPress={() => handleModalClose()} />
          </Card>
        </View>
      </Modal>
    ) : null}
  </View>
);
}
```

This is my app.js:

```
export default function App() {
 const Stack = createStackNavigator();
 const options = {
 headerStyle: { backgroundColor: '#587cc4', borderColor: '#587cc4' },
};
return (
   <View style={styles.container}>
   <Provider store={store}>
    <NavigationContainer >
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Group screenOptions={{ headerShown: false, ...TransitionPresets.FadeFromBottomAndroid }}>
          <Stack.Screen
            name="Register"
            component={Register}
            options={{ title: '' }}
          />
          <Stack.Screen
            name="Registered"
            component={Registered}
            options={{ title: '' }}
          />
          <Stack.Screen
            name="SignIn"
            component={SignIn}
            options={{ title: '' }}
          />
          <Stack.Screen
            name="Astronomy"
            component={Astronomy}
            options={{ title: '' }}
          />
          <Stack.Screen
            name="RandomAstronomy"
            component={RandomAstronomy}
            options={{ title: '' }}
          />

          <Stack.Screen
            name="MarsRoverPhotos"
            component={MarsRoverPhotos}
            options={{ title: '' }}
          />

          <Stack.Screen
            name="PlanetaryInfo"
            component={PlanetaryInfo}
            options={{ title: '' }}
          />
        </Stack.Group>
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
    </Provider>
</View>
);
}
```

This is what the error is:
This error is located at:
in Provider (created by App)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by App)
in View (created by App)
in App (created by withDevTools(App))
in withDevTools(App)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in AppContainer
in main(RootComponent), js engine: hermes

I'm not sure why it's not working or not recognizing my functions. Also when I remove the provider from the app.js and try going on to the marsrover screen I get the error there instead.

This is the error when I remove the provider function
TypeError: undefined is not a function

This error is located at:
in MarsRoverPhotos (created by SceneView)
in StaticContainer
in EnsureSingleNavigator (created by SceneView)
in SceneView (created by CardContainer)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by CardContainer)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by CardContainer)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View
in CardSheet (created by Card)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AnimatedComponent)
in AnimatedComponent
in AnimatedComponentWrapper (created by PanGestureHandler)
in PanGestureHandler (created by PanGestureHandler)
in PanGestureHandler (created by Card)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AnimatedComponent)
in AnimatedComponent
in AnimatedComponentWrapper (created by Card)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by Card)
in Card (created by CardContainer)
in CardContainer (created by CardStack)
in RNSScreen (created by AnimatedComponent)
in AnimatedComponent
in AnimatedComponentWrapper (created by InnerScreen)
in Suspender (created by Freeze)
in Suspense (created by Freeze)
in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
in DelayedFreeze (created by InnerScreen)
in InnerScreen (created by Screen)
in Screen (created by MaybeScreen)
in MaybeScreen (created by CardStack)
in RNSScreenContainer (created by ScreenContainer)
in ScreenContainer (created by MaybeScreenContainer)
in MaybeScreenContainer (created by CardStack)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by Background)
in Background (created by CardStack)
in CardStack (created by HeaderShownContext)
in RNCSafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaProvider)
in SafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaInsetsContext)
in SafeAreaProviderCompat (created by StackView)
in RNGestureHandlerRootView (created by GestureHandlerRootView)
in GestureHandlerRootView (created by StackView)
in StackView (created by StackNavigator)
in PreventRemoveProvider (created by NavigationContent)
in NavigationContent
in Unknown (created by StackNavigator)
in StackNavigator (created by App)
in EnsureSingleNavigator
in BaseNavigationContainer
in ThemeProvider
in NavigationContainerInner (created by App)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by App)
in App (created by withDevTools(App))
in withDevTools(App)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in AppContainer
in main(RootComponent), js engine: hermes